# "Authentication unsuccessful" al conectar por smtp de office365 usando PHPMailer

Tags: phpmailer, office365

El problema es que no soy capaz de conectar por SMTP de Office 365 para enviar emails usando la librería PHPMailer de PHP

```
require 'inc/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';



$phpmailer = new PHPMailer();

//Datos del email
$phpmailer->Subject = 'Asunto...';
$phpmailer->addAddress('micorreo@midominio.com');
$phpmailer->msgHTML('<h1>El mensaje...</h1>');

//Aqui configuramos el SMTP
$phpmailer->isSMTP();
$phpmailer->SMTPDebug = 2;
$phpmailer->Debugoutput = 'html';
$phpmailer->Host = "smtp.office365.com";
$phpmailer->Port = 587;
//$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$phpmailer->SMTPAuth = true;
$phpmailer->Username = "info@midominio.com";
$phpmailer->Password = "xxxxxxxxx";

//Enviamos
$resp = $phpmailer->send();
var_dump($resp);
```

La respuesta que me da el servidor es 535 5.7.3 Authentication unsuccessful.
No se si es que tengo mal la configuración o es que hay que configurar la cuenta para que aplicaciones externas puedan conectarse (Con Gmail sé que hay que activar la opción "Permitir aplicaciones menos seguras", no sé si con O365 hay alguna configuración del estilo y por eso falle)

Comment: falta el SetFrom('correro@correo.com, 'correo salida'); el manual dice que debes habilitar el tls tambien https://support.office.com/es-es/article/C%C3%B3mo-configurar-un-dispositivo-o-aplicaci%C3%B3n-multifunci%C3%B3n-para-enviar-correo-mediante-Office-365-69f58e99-c550-4274-ad18-c805d654b4c4?ui=es-ES&rs=es-ES&ad=ES

Comment: He probado con `$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'tls';` y con `$phpmailer->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';` y pasa lo mismo (de hecho con ssl me pone `Failed to connect to server`). Y lo de `SetFrom()` lo he añadidio tambien pero no es ese el problema (lo único que pasa si no se añade es que pone Root User en el remitente)

Comment: verificastes si tienes un firewall que te bloquea el puerto de salida 587?